# WebOS CLI ares-install error when trying to install app on tv

Tags: webos, lg

When trying to `ares-instal --device mytv ./path_to_my_ipk` I get the following error:

> ares-install ERR! Error: Command '/bin/rm -rf /media/developer/temp && /bin/mkdir -p /media/developer/temp' exited with code=1 (signal: undefined)

I'm currently using ares version `1.11.2-j36-k`

I've also completed this previous steps:

- `ares-setup-device` and add my tv where I've specified the IP address, and pressed enter for device port, ssh user, description and password.

- `ares-novacom --device mytv --getkey` and after that introduced the passphrase that was display on the tv

- checked if the connection was ok by running `ares-device-info --device mytv`

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue on Macos, same version of the ares CLI and I have just downloaded the webOS SDK 6.0.1.

Now when I enable the Developer Mode on the TV, it says to use webOS TV CLI v1.12.4 or later, if not, I will not be able to install apps using the Developer Mode.

The correct CLI version is available here, with steps to install: [https://webostv.developer.lge.com/develop/tools/cli-installation#:~:text=webOS_TV_CLI_mac_1.12.4](https://webostv.developer.lge.com/develop/tools/cli-installation#:%7E:text=webOS_TV_CLI_mac_1.12.4)

Comment: I've managed to find a solution to my problem.

As stupid as it sounds, it was as simple as making sure that I was using the latest webOS version.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).